# React Native - Error: Failed to load configuration of your project

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, command

I tried to **create a react native app** but I'm getting error when I run **"npx react-native init newProject"** this command. Can someone help how can I create a react native app and why I'm getting this error everytime

**strong text**[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it by specifying a lower version

`npx react-native@0.70 init AwesomeProject --version 0.70`